# Create object with keys matching union members

Tags: typescript

I have a union type like:

```
type messageType = "start" | "stop";
```

Is it possible to generate an object with the following type signature:

```
let value: { [k in messageType]: [] } = {
  /* what goes here ??? */
};
```

using ONLY `messageType` values? Or do I need to manually specify them?

Comment: If you don't want to repeat the keys, you have to go the other way round - initialize the object, then define union type like `type messageType = keyof typeof value;`

Answer (score 2):

> Or do I need to manually specify them

You need to specify them manually

```
type messageType = "start" | "stop";

let value: { [k in messageType]: [] } = {
  /* manually filled out */
  start: [],
  stop: [],
};
```